# KeyboardEvent: how to get numeric key code while 'Shift' is pressed?

Tags: javascript, angular, keyboard-events

In my application, I need to identify if the user pressed any of the number keys (either main keyboard or numpad) as well as if shift/ctrl/alt keys are pressed at the same time.

I need this because the pressed key represents the number in the array (from 0 to 9) which should trigger an action with this number. So my logic is simple:

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeydownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  let index = Number(event.key);
  if (isNaN(index)) {
    // skip, for now
  }else{
    doAction(index);
  }
}
```

I like this because of its readability and transparency.

It seems that things are simple when I additionally need to handle 'Alt' or 'Ctrl'. In these cases, event.key still represents a numeric key value of the key pressed (like '1' or '2') (and I can check event.ctrlKey/event.altKey.

But things are getting more complicated when I need to consider the 'Shift' key. In this case, event.key does not represent a numeric key. Instead, it represents other characters such as '!' or '@'.

I guess I could convert this into key code by building a map, but I'd need to handle keyboard layouts as in some cases Shift+2 will end up to be a '@', in other - '"' (Russian layout vs English).

What is the proper and simple way to detect the code of the key pressed when the 'Shift' button is pressed?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the entire event object of the keydown event. There are other properties. One that represents the key code (not the character typed) and a boolean that flags as true if shift was held down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. Uisng event.which: It returns numeric value but it is deprecated.
2. Your idea of creating map is cool. To create the map, instead of using "event.key", use "event.code".

EVENT.CODE is your life saver.

Comment: So, still need a map, just use other property of the event object. Ok. If that's the only option.

Answer (score 0):

A modern solution is

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  // ...
  const matches = /Digit([0-9])/.exec(e.code);
  if (matches) {
    const digit = +matches[1];
    console.log(digit);
    // ...
  }
});
```